# Why doesn't a single JQuery-based content slider work for me? (bxSlider, commas in js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to incorporate a JQuery-based content slider on my website for a long time now, but I haven't been able to get a single one to work. Here is the relevant bit of code in the webpage's php:

```
<ul class="bxSlider">
        <?php
            $poemquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Act1Poems ORDER BY id asc") or die(mysql_error());
            $currentElement = 0;
            $totalElements = 0;
            while($poem = mysql_fetch_array($poemquery)) {
                echo '<li class="poem">';
                echo $poem['Poem'];
                echo '</li>';

                $totalElements++;
            }
            $currentElement = $poem['ID'];

        ?>
        </ul>
```

Notice that it pulls paragraphs from a MySQL database to add content slides to the bxSlider. And yet, I get this result:
[image]

That is the two entries of the table laid on top of one another, in the fashion of a normal unordered list. So it's not applying the actual slider.

Just to be sure, I tried a regular list instead of having fancy mysql stuff. No luck there, either:
[image]

It's not just BxSlider. LightSlider and (I think) Jssor Slider haven't worked for me either. Something that's been happening pretty consistently is this error:
[image]

That error manifests itself as "unexpected token ," half the time, and most of the time, completely breaks my javascript. And it comes up every time I use commas in my javascript code for some crazy reason, which means it's only okay with me using:

```
$('.bxslider').bxslider();
```

Which is okay, except that that doesn't let me customize the slider(along with it already not working to begin with). Even lightSlider demands the same thing:

```
var slider = $('#publicMethods').lightSlider({
    slideMargin:4,
    slideWidth:200,
    loop:false
});
```

I've tried both these sliders with and without their included css files.

So, what the heck?

Sorry that my first question here is so vague. I hope the scope of it isn't huge. This is my first major web project. But if it helps, I've added the sourcecode of the entire project sans database info to the reference txt by way of pastebin.

The ultimate goal is for it to show only one paragraph at a time, and for the user to be able to click buttons or swipe to read each paragraph in order from the table.

Pastebin 1 (PHP/HTML): http://pastebin.com/6uY77hC2
Pastebin 2 (CSS): http://pastebin.com/jh9AFLpJ
Pastebin 3 (JS): http://pastebin.com/TPXbBZR6

Comment: It feels to me that the actual problem is Js syntax issue,there is some trailing/stray commas. Can you create JS fiddle example with your full Js code, you can hard code the <li>'s. I just need to see your full JS code ?.

Comment: Have u tried to Js lint your Js file? Put your code here to check if there are some syntax issues http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: First of all, thanks so much to scimonster for inlining the images/pastebin for convenience and to sanjeev for the suggestions. The full js code is now linked in the question, so you can use that. Here is my attempt at replicating this through jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c1kqeLt4/ I'm probably doing this wrong, but so far no luck.

Comment: On the other hand, jslint tells me I've got about a thousand problems with my javascript file!! I had no idea I've been formatting the thing wrong this whole time. JSHint on jsfiddle at least says what I fed into it was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your selector name , in html class name is class="bxSlider" (S is caps) but in Js you are using $('.bxslider') (s is small) , thats why in your JS it is not selecting the element correctly and your slider is not created.

Also note, the function name is bxSlider() not bxslider() (again typo).

Updated your JS fiddle and its working now http://jsfiddle.net/c1kqeLt4/3/

```
$('.bxSlider').bxSlider({
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 1,
    slideWidth: 100
});
```

For css part, it is not working because Bxslider adds `style 'float:left'` on `<li>`, so height of ul becomes zero. Give background on `<li>` and it will work.

Updated JS fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c1kqeLt4/7

Comment: I can't believe I made that dumb mistake in both my project and my jsfiddle. Still, after fixing it in the html and css files, I've got no slider, and in the project itself, it removes the CSS formatting from my list, even though the names match? What a headache. http://jsfiddle.net/c1kqeLt4/6/

Comment: The slider is working in this JSFiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/c1kqeLt4/3/ ,the JS fiddle you gave just now has function name .bxslider({}),it should be bxSlider({});

Comment: For css,  it is not working because Bxslider add style 'float:left' on <li> so height of ul becomes zero, give background on <li> and it will work. Updated JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c1kqeLt4/7/

Comment: Wow, I had the whole thing backwards. Thank you, Sanjeev, you're a hero. Once I figure out how to properly format this like in the first reference picture, I'll be set for life.

Comment: Please mark it answered if my solution fixed your problem.